# Echo command is not printing space

Tags: python, shell, sh

My echo is not considering Space character.
Description="short message is required"

Export Description

I'm using this Description variable in my Python script but when executing my script its printing 'short'. Basically its not printing anything after the space character.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and what can be the solution?
I want to printing everything inside the double quotes of echo command.
Also, what can be the alternative of space characters?

Comment: please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What's the command exactly? You have tags for both Python and shell, so which one is it? Or if both, what are you doing with one, and what with the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's subprocess module to execute your shell command.
You code would be as follows:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "export Description='short message is required'"
ret = subprocess.run(
            cmd,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            shell=True,
            executable='/bin/bash'
        )

print(ret)
```

Exported variable from console will return following:

```
root@DEB:~# export Description='short message is required'
root@DEB:~# echo $Description 
short message is required
root@DEB:~#
```